# Repeating Processes on python but with mixed variables

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, youtube-dl

Currently im trying to finish a script to pass links from a youtube playlist trough youtube_dl to be able to stream the audio from them on to a player on my raspberry pi, but I don't know how to repeat a process but changing the variable automatically without changing every single number on the array like so:

```
import os
import pafy
import youtube_dl as yt
from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL

links = ["http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JaSfjAIcGpQ",
        "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pzAo3Hj15R4",
        "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hWdovALEen0",
        "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JVpTp8IHdEg",
        "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pw-0pbY9JeU",
        "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lrfhf1Gv4Tw",
        "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ilw-qmqZ5zY",
        "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UwsY_foobEw",
        "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RSNmgE6L8AU",
        "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d020hcWA_Wg",
        "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O4irXQhgMqg",
        "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9P16xvwMQ5A",
        "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fregObNcHC8",
        "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fLN6ec7-43s",
        "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DcHKOC64KnE",
        "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UYwF-jdcVjY",
        "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jQcBwE6j09U",
        "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lXgkuM2NhYI",
        "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vabnZ9-ex7o",
        "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=neNJvLIKaOk",
        "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k4V3Mo61fJM",
        "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pstVCGyaUBM",
        "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D8Ymd-OCucs",
        "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SeRJb3U1v3A",
        "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J0DjcsK_-HY",
        "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f2JuxM-snGc",
        "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Eyjj8BgsBGU",
        "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dX3k_QDnzHE",
        "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=luM6oeCM7Yw",
        "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5iC0YXspJRM",
        "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BnOVufgbIzA",
        "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wwK_Kmh0P90",
        "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UYfh9YhUVdE"]


y = YoutubeDL({
    'format': 'bestaudio',
})
url = links[0]
r = y.extract_info(url, download=False)
print(r['ext'])
print(r['url'])
```

I am trying to change the part of "links[0]" 
so i can repeat this process but without changing the number manually, but instead doing it in python. Im still new at python.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to iterate over the list. You can make it with a for loop.
Like so:

```
for link in links:
    url = link
    r = y.extract_info(url, download=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer above seems okay, just to add on other ways to do it:
Shortest version:

```
extracted_details_list = [y.extract_info(url, download=False) for url in links] # list comprehension
```

A long version, could be easier to get the flow of for-loops:

```
for i in range(len(links)):
    url = links[i]
    r = y.extract_info(url, download=False)
    print(r['ext'])
    print(r['url']
```